# When to stop exploring and start exploiting in multi-armed bandit problem

Tags: algorithms, monte-carlo, gambling

I'm reading [Algorithms to Live By: The Computer Science of Human Decisions](https://algorithmstoliveby.com/#aboutthebook) and it came to a conclusion that in the problem described below, the optimal strategy is to stop exploring after 38 observations. **How did they arrive at 38?**

> In a simple demonstration of this phenomenon, published in 1966, Amos Tversky and Ward Edwards conducted experiments where people were shown a box with two lights on it and told that each light would turn on a fixed (but unknown) percentage of the time. They were then given 1,000 opportunities either to observe which light came on, or to place a bet on the outcome without getting to observe it. (Unlike a more traditional bandit problem setup, here one could not make a “pull” that was both wager and observation at once; participants would not learn whether their bets had paid off until the end.) This is pure exploration vs. exploitation, pitting the gaining of information squarely against the use of it. For the most part, people adopted a sensible strategy of observing for a while, then placing bets on what seemed like the best outcome—but they consistently spent a lot more time observing than they should have. How much more time? In one experiment, one light came on 60% of the time and the other 40% of the time, a difference neither particularly blatant nor particularly subtle. In that case, people chose to observe 505 times, on average, placing bets the other 495 times. But the math says they should have started to bet after just 38 observations—leaving 962 chances to cash in."

Comment: This is probably not related to algorithms very much. It is just a probability and expectation calculation problem.

Comment: The book has a bibliography. For example, your experiment is, according to the book, from the paper "Information versus reward in binary choices", which further refers to the book "Sequential Analysis" by Wald, which one can get from the Internet Archive.

There, chapter 5 is probably the one you're looking for.